# Does the future returned from std::async with the launch::deferred policy block in the destructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, future, stdasync

In the description of the `std::async` it is said that:

> If the `std::future` obtained from `std::async` is not moved from or bound
> to a reference, the destructor of the `std::future` will block at the
> end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes,
> essentially making code such as the following synchronous:
>
> ```cpp
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
> std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
> ```
>
> (note that the destructors of std::futures
> obtained by means other than a call to std::async never block)

This statement is confusing, and I don't clearly understand what should be the behavior in case of `std::launch::deferred` policy. Ok, the experiment shows that it doesn't block, but I wonder whether the standard explicitly says that the future returned from `std::async` with the `std::launch::deferred` policy doesn't block in destructor.

This opens another follow-up question regarding the default policy: if the future returned from `std::async` blocks in destructor in case of `std::launch::async` and doesn't block in case of `std::launch::deferred`, that should lead to very inconsistent behavior in case of the default (`std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred`) policy. Recently I was asking of the semantics of `std::async` with default launch policy: [What is the semantics of std::async with automatic (launch::async|launch::deferred) launch policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63164245/what-is-the-semantics-of-stdasync-with-automatic-launchasynclaunchdeferr), this example confuses me even more, and the applicability of the pattern where we don't explicitly know the platform selection of the policy, is very questionable.

**Update:** I found a proposal to the standard [P0701r1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0701r1.html#conditional-blocking-in-futures-destructor-must-go) that doesn't fully answer my question, but if this proposal would be accepted, it would solve the ambiguity of blocking/non-blocking destructors.

Comment: [This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) might answer the question, but that *"may*" is annoying. It isn't clear to me if blocking is optional, or if it's just an unfortunate use of the word.

Comment: It is disappointing that this question didn't get more attention. I think it may have been posted too late in the day, when user activity drops a lot.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, May we boost the attention somehow? Meanwhile I found a partial answer on the problem: there is a proposal P0701r1 to unify the `std::future` behavior and not block in the destructor. I also plan to contact one of the teams in my organization that participates in C++ standartization.

Comment: Editing the question with additional information brings up on the recently active questions list. You can add your latest finds to your question.